# Printing System information in printout

Tags: vb.net

So whenever I print, it prints out "System.Windows.Forms.Label, Text". I can only assume that this is because I am trying to put a label to a string... but whats the easiest and best way to fix this?

Additionally, on the very last page of the printout it prints "System.Collections.Generic.List`[System.String]... which is fine, I can reuse the paper... but it would be nice if it didn't do that... I have attached all code relevant to my print out, please let me know if you need more...

Any additional suggestions are welcome (:   Thanks!

```
        Private lines As New List(Of String)


Private loopCount As Integer
Private WithEvents docToPrint As New Printing.PrintDocument

Private Sub btnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    lines.Clear()
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("Date:" & DateTimePicker1.Value)
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("Company Information: ")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("Company Name: " & txtCustName.ToString)
    lines.Add("Part Name: " & txtPartName.ToString)
    lines.Add("Qty per Year: " & yearQty.ToString)
    lines.Add("Qty per Batch/Shipment: " & batchQty.ToString)
    lines.Add("Equipment Used Information: ")
    lines.Add("Vib Machine Used: " & lblVMachineName.ToString)
    lines.Add("Vibratory Media Used: " & lblVibMedia.ToString)
    lines.Add("Liquid Compound Name: " & lblCompname.ToString)
    lines.Add("Labor Cost Per Run: " & laborCostpRun.ToString("C2") & "     Per Peice: " & laborCostpPc.ToString("C2") & "     Per Year: " & laborcostpYr.ToString("C2"))
    lines.Add("Media Cost Per Run: " & mediaCostpRun.ToString("C2") & "     Per Peice: " & mediaCostpPc.ToString("C2") & "     Per Year: " & mediaCostpYr.ToString("C2"))
    lines.Add("Machine Cost per Run: " & machineCostpRun.ToString("C2") & "  Per Peice:: " & machineCostpPc.ToString("C2") & "    Per Year: " & machineCostpYr.ToString("C2"))
    lines.Add("Compound Cost per Run: " & compoundPricepRun.ToString("C2") & "Per Peice: " & compCostpPc.ToString("C2") & "     Per Year: " & compCostpYr.ToString("C2"))
    lines.Add("Factory Overhead per Run: " & factOH.ToString("C2") & "Per Peice: " & facOHpPc.ToString("C2") & "   Per Year: " & facOHpYr.ToString("C2"))
    lines.Add("Total Process Cost per Run: " & processCost.ToString("C2") & "Per Peice: " & processCostpPc.ToString("C2") & "   Per Year: " & processCostpYr.ToString("C2"))
    lines.Add("Business Overhead per Run: " & bOH.ToString("C2") & "Per Peice: " & bOHpPC.ToString("C2") & "   Per Year: " & boOHpYr.ToString("C2"))
    lines.Add("Sales Commision per Run: " & salesComm.ToString("C2") & "Per Peice: " & salesCommpPc.ToString("C2") & "   Per Year: " & salesCommpYr.ToString("C2"))
    lines.Add("Profit per Run: " & profit.ToString("C2") & "Per Peice: " & profitpPc.ToString("C2") & "   Per Year: " & profitpYr.ToString("C2"))
    lines.Add("Total Price per Run: " & grandTotalpRun.ToString("C2") & "Per Peice: " & grandTotalpPc.ToString("C2") & "   Per Year: " & grandTotalpYr.ToString("C2"))
    lines.Add("Runs per Week: " & runspWeek.ToString)
    lines.Add("Runs per Year: " & runspYear.ToString)
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("Parameters:")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("As for media, the following costs are implemented:")
    lines.Add("HD-1 Cone: Price: $1.47/lb ; Density/lb: 100 ; Wear Rate: .5")
    lines.Add("F 3/16 Cyl.: Price: $1.54/lb ; Density/lb: 95 ; Wear Rate: 0")
    lines.Add("ECH 7/8 T2: Price: $1.14/lb ; Density/lb: 95 ; Wear Rate: .3")
    lines.Add("ECH 7/16 Cyl: Price: $1.10/lb ; Density/lb: 95 ; Wear Rate: .3")
    lines.Add("3/16 Steel Ball Cone: Price: $3.50/lb ; Density/lb: 270 ; Wear Rate: 0")
    lines.Add("UFX 3/8X3/8 ACT: Price: $.86/lb ; Density/lb: 100 ; Wear Rate: 1")
    lines.Add("XC 7/8 Cyl.: Price: $1.10/lb ; Density/lb: 95 ; Wear Rate: .35")
    lines.Add("LD-2 3/4 Cone: Price: $1.40/lb ; Density/lb: 70 ; Wear Rate: .2")
    lines.Add("HD-1 Tri-Star 1-3/8 X 1/2: Price: $1.47/lb ; Density/lb: 100 ; Wear Rate: .5")
    lines.Add("5/16 Steel Ball Cone: Price: $2.75/lb ; Density/lb: 270 ; Wear Rate: 0")
    lines.Add("25/32 Steel Cone: Price: $3.25/lb ; Density/lb: 270 ; Wear Rate: 0")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("As for machines, the following costs are implemented: ")
    lines.Add("Torex TG-299F: $2/hr")
    lines.Add("Sweco 1.2: $2/hr")
    lines.Add("Torex 6026A: $9/hr")
    lines.Add("Torex 6026B: $9/hr")
    lines.Add("Sweco FM10: $5/hr")
    lines.Add("Sweco FM7: $5/hr")
    lines.Add("VT-5524 F: $11/hr")
    lines.Add("VT-5524 F: $11/hr")
    lines.Add("VTHT-2450: $9/hr")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("As for compounds, the following costs are implemented:")
    lines.Add("Rodeco 211: $3.96/gal")
    lines.Add("Rodeco 551: $4.02/gal")
    lines.Add("Rodeco 553: $6.90/gal")
    lines.Add("Rodeco 4677: $5.48/gal")
    lines.Add("Rodeco 842: $3.74/gal")
    lines.Add("Rodeco 320: $3.42/gal")
    lines.Add("Rodeco 103: $ .89/lb")
    lines.Add("Rodeco 307: $ .79/lb")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("Business Overhead Includes:")
    lines.Add("Office phone, officer salary, bank, dues + subscribitions, employee gifts, rent, accounting, outside maint.,")
    lines.Add(" utilities, office wages. For 2014 this was $463,000.")
    lines.Add("Since 2014 Job Shop Sales was 4% of total sales. 463,000 * 4% = $18,500. ")
    lines.Add("Divided by 4000 direct labor hours, equals 4.65/hr direct labor costs.")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("Factory Overhead Includes: ")
    lines.Add("Item:        Total 2014 Rodeco:      Vib Job Shop        Equip Cost")
    lines.Add("Repair:              $ 27                    $  7                  $ 20")
    lines.Add("Shop Supplies        $ 22                    $ 22                      ")
    lines.Add("Supervisor Labor     $ 50                    $ 20                      ")
    lines.Add("Shop Office          $  2                    $  2                      ")
    lines.Add("Rent                 $167                    $ 24                      ")
    lines.Add("Elect                $ 32                    $  5                  $ 20")
    lines.Add("Business Ins.                                $ 27                  $  3")
    lines.Add("Computer                                     $ 22                  $  3")
    lines.Add("Outside                                      $  2                      ")
    lines.Add("Wastewater                                   $  2                  $  2")
    lines.Add("Deprecition          $ 81                    $ 5                   $ 12")
    lines.Add("                                 $95,000/4000(labor hrs)=       52000/54.45(indirect hrs)    ")
    lines.Add("                                       $23.75/hr            $9.50/hr")
    lines.Add("Sales Commision: 6% of Profit. Profit is 35%")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    docToPrint.Print()

    Dim printer As New myPrinter

End Sub
Private Sub document_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    PrintDialog1.AllowSomePages = True
    PrintDialog1.ShowHelp = True

    PrintDialog1.Document = docToPrint

    Dim result As DialogResult = PrintDialog1.ShowDialog()

    If (result = DialogResult.OK) Then
        docToPrint.Print()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub document_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, _
   ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) _
       Handles docToPrint.PrintPage

    Dim printFont As New System.Drawing.Font _
        ("Arial", 12, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular)



    Dim row As Integer = 5
    For i = loopCount To lines.Count - 1
        If Not row >= e.MarginBounds.Bottom - 20 Then
            loopCount = i
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lines(i), printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 10, row)
            row += 20
        Else
            e.HasMorePages = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next


    ' Draw the content.
    e.Graphics.DrawString(lines.ToString(), printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 10, 10)
End Sub
```

Comment: You've not shared enough code to solve the problem: what is `lines` and what is `docToPrint`? It's impossible to tell what's actually happening. However, your initial question regarding the bad output is possibly related to your use of `companyName.ToString()` where `companyName` is presumably a control. Try `companyName.Text` if it's a textbox, to get the content of the box.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I actually noticed that I posted my lame attempt at fixing it... but it didn't work... but above it pretty much all of the code related to printing. If you need more let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost every control has a `Text` property to reffer to its text content.

Then, you should use that property:

```
lines.Add("Vib Machine Used: " & lblVMachineName.Text)
lines.Add("Vibratory Media Used: " & lblVibMedia.Text)
lines.Add("Liquid Compound Name: " & lblCompname.Text)
```

The same for TextBoxes in case of `txtCustName` and the other are textboxes.

Note that no `.ToString` extension is need because the `Control.Text` property is a **String** datatype, it does not need a conversion.